# asp.net bootstrap select list-group box remove items

Tags: javascript, c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I have a drop down and a list group box. on the drop down change event I need to remove all the items and add new items.

Below is the list group box

```
  <select style="max-height: 30vh; min-height: 30vh; width: 100%; border: 0;"
                        multiple="multiple"
                        class="list-group list-group-available-items overflow-auto">
                    @foreach (var listGroupOption in Model.OrderItems ?? new List<SelectListItem>())
                    {
                        <option value="@listGroupOption.Value" class="list-group-item">
                            @listGroupOption.Text
                        </option>
                    }
                </select>
```

This is my try at JavaScript

```
$('#ddlRegion').change(function (e) {

            $(".list - group - available - items")
                    .find('option')
                    .remove();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple remove, we can try to use `empty` all of option

```
$(".list-group-available-items").empty();
```

or use `remove` by option like

```
$(".list-group-available-items option").remove();
```

if we need to append new option after remove all option we can try to use `append`

```js
$(".list-group-available-items option").remove();

$(".list-group-available-items").append($('<option>', { 
        value: 'newOption',
        text : 'newOption' 
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="list-group-available-items">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that worked  , could you also give a snippet how to add new items to it.

Comment: @user565992 I had added some sample in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to first empty the existing list with .empty() and then append new options with append():

```
const myButton = document.getElementById('btn');
        myButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            $(".list-group-available-items").empty();
            $(".list-group-available-items").append('<option value="newval1">New Item 1</option>');
            $(".list-group-available-items").append('<option value="newval2">New Item 2</option>');
            $(".list-group-available-items").append('<option value="newval3">New Item 3</option>');
        });
```